# How can I force the use of sparse diagonalization methods?

Tags: matrix, sparse-arrays

When I evaluate the `Eigenvalues` function on a very large (e.g. 2^16 x 2^16) sparse matrix, *Mathematica* says something like:

> Because finding 65536 out of the 65536 eigenvalues and/or eigenvectors is likely to be faster with dense matrix methods, the sparse input matrix will be converted.

Naturally, by doing the automatic conversion to a dense matrix, my machine runs out of RAM, and I have 128 GB.

Is there a way to force *Mathematica* to use sparse methods only, albeit the computation will be slower?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Do you really, truly need all the eigenvalues? It's possible to set things so that you just have the largest few or the smallest few. Also, apart from sparsity, does your matrix have any other structure in it?

Comment: You might wish to experiment with some of the many `Method` options available for `Eigenvalues`.

Comment: Yes, I need all the eigenvalues. I tried all available `Method`s. I even tried to get the eigenvalues one-by-one, which almost works: i.e. in that case, the sparse array is not automatically converted to non-sparse one, but the ordering of the eigenvalues is non-consitent (is this a bug?). I get some eigenvalues multiple times, some are missing. The matrices I have are real and symmetric, but I don't think this plays any role here. It would be reasonable to have a switch to forbid the automatic sparse-array conversion.

Comment: "real and symmetric" - but not banded, or even tridiagonal?

Comment: No, not banded nor tridiagonal.

Comment: If a reasonably simple formula exists for generating your matrix, please provide it.  Thanks.